# Conditional probability on a chain of events

Tags: probability

I just have a question about conditional probabilities and Bayes' Rule. 
If you have, let us say, three events $A$, $B$ and $C$, with non-null probabilities, are there conditions under which
$$
P(A|C) = P(A|B) \cdot P(B|C) ?
$$
I am almost sure that it is not true in general (according to Bayes' Theorem), but writing this is the only way for my calculations to give a result consistent with the problem I try to solve.

Thanks a lot for any help or hint.

Comment: Suppose $P(B|C)=1$.

Comment: If $P(A| \neg B)=0$ and $P(B| \neg C)=0$ then the equation is valid.

Comment: Otherwise, it is **P(A|C) = P(A|B)*P(B|C) + P(A|non B)P(non B|C)**, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Roll two fair dice, and let $C$ be the event that the sum of the rolls is 3. Let $A$ be the event that the first roll is a 1, and $B$ the event that the first roll is a 2. Then $\mathbb{P}(A|C)\neq 0$, but $\mathbb{P}(A|B)=0$ so the right-hand side is zero.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it ;-)